# Username uniqueness cs50 finance

Tags: python, cs50

When I enter a taken username I expect to see Username Taken error. Instead I get a 500 internal server error and a `RuntimeError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.username` in the terminal. Please help.

```
result = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(:username, :password)",username=request.form.get("username"),password=generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))
#Username uniqueness
if not result:
    return apology("The username is already taken", 400)`
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the predictable and expected outcome from sqlite. The `execute` fails because it *cannot* insert a duplicate username by definition. (Review the users table schema to remember why). What to do? Two possible choices:

- query (with a select) the users table to see if `username` already exists. Depending on that result, program should try the insert, or not.
- read up on and implement an  [ON CONFLICT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) clause in the INSERT query.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved using a try: except: like this:

## Generate a hashed password from the user's input information

```
    hashed = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
    username = request.form.get("username")

    # Add username and hashed password to the users table.
    try:
        information = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (?, ?)", username, hashed)
    except:
        # If the username already exists.
        return apology("Username already in use", 403)
```